# WooCommerce Shop page add custom html to page only once

Tags: php, html, woocommerce

I want to add some custom HTML in the Shop page only once. This will be used as a modal which which will open on demand. I know I can use javascript for this but I want to do this in php. I can use WooCommerce hooks but not sure what is the best hook for this so this html is added only once for the whole Shop page?

Example:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content','add_foo', 2 );
function add_foo(){
     echo '<div class="foo"></div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `wp_head` or `wp_footer` to make the modal HTML available through JavaScript on every page and then use some JavaScript trigger to make the modal visible.

```php
add_action('wp_head','add_foo');
function add_foo(){
    ?>
    <script>
        var modal = '<div class="foo"></div>'
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: I am using this in the plugin. What if theme does not have wp_head or wp_footer? Can   I detect that or create backup of sort?

Comment: If the theme doesn’t have a `wp_head` or `wp_footer` (which 99.9% of all themes have), then simply add the code manually to your theme.